# Transform matrix issue with IE 8/9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, matrix, svg, css-transforms

I am trying to get the transform matrix for SVG objects on my webpage. Here is the current statement I use to make sure it is picked up by one of the four CSS transform properties:

```
$("#printdiv svg").each(function(){

    var webkitMatrix = false;

    var transform = $(this).css("transform");

    if (transform == null || transform.indexOf("matrix") == -1)
       transform = $(this).css("-ms-transform");

    if (transform == null || transform.indexOf("matrix") == -1)
        transform = $(this).css("-moz-transform");

    if (transform == null || transform.indexOf("matrix") == -1){
        transform = $(this).css("-webkit-transform");
        webkitMatrix = true;
    }

    /* do stuff with matrix */

});
```

(The reason I have a var "webkitMatrix" is because the function must parse the `-webkit-transform` matrix differently if true)

My problem is (like most everything that I do) IE10, Chrome, and FireFox pick up a matrix just fine, but IE 8/9 do not.

Here you can see the result of printing each CSS property to the console when using IE10 in IE9 mode/standards and FireFox (latest):
[image: Transform comparison IE9 and FF]
(Larger version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g07q4.png)

Is there something that I can use, maybe a `filter:` or a different transform property so I can get my SVG information?

Comment: IE8 does not support SVGs nor CSS transforms. If you could provide a working fiddle, it would be much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I can't, as it is a project for my workplace. I am unable to provide a fiddle or additional code, sorry.

Comment: First of all jQuery takes care of vendor prefixes itself. Second, afaik IE does not support css transforms on svg objects.

Comment: Not at all? It renders the SVG, I just need the information. Is there any alternative to obtaining information instead of transform for IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IE9**

You can resolve a SVG matrix like so:

```
svgElement = document.getElementById("mySVG_ID");
var matrixIE = new Array();
matrixIE[0] = svgElement.createSVGMatrix().a;
matrixIE[1] = svgElement.createSVGMatrix().c; //C and B are switched
matrixIE[2] = svgElement.createSVGMatrix().b;
matrixIE[3] = svgElement.createSVGMatrix().d;
matrixIE[4] = $("#mySVG_ID").css("left");
matrixIE[5] = $("#mySVG_ID").css("top");
```

**IE8**

Leaflet uses VML objects instead of SVG objects for incompatible browsers. VML elements have the class name `.leaflet-vml-shape`. Because I rely on `html2canvas` to render my pages as images, and `html2canvas` does not work under IE8, there was no reason for me to research how to resolve a VML matrix.